# Modal de Bootstrap muestra el backdrop pero no el contenido

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, vue.js

Mi problema  es el siguiente, estoy trabajando con Vue y quiero mostrar un modal a partir de un boton.

```
openModal: function () {
            $('#newAddress').modal('show');
        },
```

Esta función la llamo con @click en un boton. Pero cuando lo ejecuto solo aparece el backdrop.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el codigo del modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="newAddress" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title title">Añadir Sede</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label>Nombre:</label>
                    <input v-model="location.name" id="name" class="multisteps-form__input form-control" type="text"
                           placeholder="Digita el nombre de la sede"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label>Dirección:</label>
                    <input v-model="location.address" class="multisteps-form__input form-control" type="text"
                           placeholder="Digita la dirección de la sede"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label>Barrio:</label>
                    <input v-model="location.neighborhood " class="multisteps-form__input form-control" type="text"
                           placeholder="Digita el barrio de la sede."/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label>Celular:</label>
                    <input v-model="location.phone" class="multisteps-form__input form-control" type="text"
                           placeholder="Digita el numero de contacto con la sede"/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button @click="saveLocation" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero alguno me pueda ayudar, ya perdi mucho tiempo con esto, y se que debe ser alguna cosa pequeña. No se si puede tener relación el hecho que cambie la plantilla que estaba utilizando.

Comment: intentaste alterar el css del modal?

Comment: Si, pero mira que parece que es algo con el javascript, cuando lo abro con las opciones default data-target y así funciona, pero desde javascript no. Por ahora lo deje con el data-target para no perder más tiempo pero aun no encuentro una solución.

Comment: que version de laravel usas?